# Flex building an application with client side and server side

Tags: flash, apache-flex, upload

I am totally new to Flex and Flash, basically I want to create an application that has these features
- At client side: Display a list of images, when user click on one image, data will be stored in MySQL database.
- At server side: Manage images used in client side, I can delete, add new images.

Is  this possible for me to achieve this using Flex? And if it is able,  will my output be 2 separate SWF files? And where can I find the  materials to read on writing such applications?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Flex is client only as far as I am aware, there is no Adobe server based on Flex.

For small stuff, low performance stuff, PHP will probably fill all your server side scripting needs.

There is Haxe though, which comes pretty close to Flex(ActionScript) in syntax and other stuff, but it's a separate language. It can be used with Neko virtual machine on the server side.

Though, if you are used to programming server side in Java, or any other language, use what you're familiar with.

If not, pick something and learn it (PHP?, Java, Haxe, ASP etc).

Basically, Flex is only client side as far as I am aware, and you will be doing most things either via http requests (you don't seem to need sockets).

So, **I would recommend PHP + Flex** unless you need server amazing server side performance, in which case I'll leave the choosing to you.

Just start learning Flex and then read about URLRequest and learn a little bit more about PHP and stuff like that. Use a Google search, and things will start popping up.

Comment: From a theoretical standpoint, one could write a server in ActionScript using the socket APIs and Adobe AIR.  There would need to be a highly specialized case for me to recommend that approach.

Comment: So AIR can listen for incoming sockets... interesting capability... I just noticed the SocketServer class in google... It seems to be more about application usage then about server usage but yes, it seems possible